# p5.play - rotate collider along with sprite

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm using [p5.play](https://github.com/molleindustria/p5.play/) and I'm trying to have my sprite rotated at a slight angle, and I need a collider on it as well. I can do this:

```js
let sprite = createSprite(x, y, width, height);
sprite.setCollider("rectangle", 0, 0, width, height);
```

But this doesn't rotate the collider, just makes it larger.

[image: result]

What I need is a collider matching the sprite, like here:

[image: expected result]

The `setCollider` function seems to ignore the rotation too.

Is it an error on my end or the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the [documenation](http://molleindustria.github.io/p5.play/docs/classes/Sprite.html) for p5.play, it sounds like this is not possible:

> The sprite's current collider. It can either be an Axis Aligned Bounding Box (a non-rotated rectangle) or a circular collider.

So it sounds like if you want more advanced collision detection, you're going to have to do it manually. Googling something like "rotated rectangle collision detection" will return a ton of results.